# iOS: Nested UIPageViewController missing scroll behavior

Tags: ios, nested, uipageviewcontroller

[image]

Hello, I have two UIPageViewController, The main one is with horizontal scroll direction, every page on it contains a vertical UIPageViewController. Every thing work fine like in the picture. But what I want is, for example when I am in page 3b, and that I do scroll from left to right the application go to the page 2a. For the moment horizontal scroll works only when I am in pages 1a, 2a, 3a and 4a. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you found any solution ?